# Regular expression with Sed and storing output in variable python

Tags: python, regex, sed

I'm trying to retrieve the default gateway from a users PC. They will be running either OSX or linux.

So far I'm using `route -n get default | grep gateway` which gives me output such as `gateway 192.168.1.254` I want to just take "192.168.1.254" omitting the word gateway.

I've tried using `route -n get default | grep gateway | sed "[0-9]+` but that doesn't seem to work.

I have two questions:

1) Why isn't the regular expression working?

2) What modules can I use to retrieve the output of the command to store in variable rather than just the return code like `subprocess.call()` ?

Comment: Are you sure that this `route -n get default | grep gateway` command returns `gateway 192.168.1.254` output?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same grep itself.

```
route -n get default | grep 'gateway' | grep -o '[0-9.]\+'
```

OR

You could use `awk`

```
route -n get default | awk '/gateway/{print $2}'
```

In python, you could use `subprocess.check_output` function to store the output of shell command to a particular python variable.

```
result = subprocess.check_output("""route -n get default | awk '/gateway/{print $2}'""", shell=True)
```

Comment: I'm still getting `gateway: 192.168.1.254` instead of just `192.168.1.254` with both of your lines.

Picture: http://iforce.co.nz/i/n2dxwhxx.zvq.png

Comment: you need to use `-o` parameter in grep to print only the match. Check my update..

Answer (score 0):

why you don’t use:

```
var = os.popen(shell cmd).read()
```

to save the output data.

Then, you just:

```
print var
```

To, check and debug your output.

Answer (score 0):

Doing most of it in Python;

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: data = subprocess.check_output(['route', '-n', 'get', 'default'])

In [3]: data = data.decode('utf-8').splitlines()

In [4]: for ln in data:
   ...:     if 'gateway' in ln:
   ...:         gw = ln.split()[1]
   ...:         break
   ...:     

In [5]: gw
Out[5]: '192.168.178.1'
```

I'm using Python 3.4 here, hence the `decode()` in `In[3]`.